# how to decode a json string and add to array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, recursion

I have a few records from database and I fetched all records. The array return as the code below

```
array (size=10)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'type' => string 'group' (length=5)
      'members' => null
      'parents' => string '0' (length=1)
      'level' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'type' => string 'group' (length=5)
      'members' => null
      'parents' => string '0' (length=1)
      'level' => string '1' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=5)
      'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'type' => string 'team' (length=4)
      'members' => string '["3","5","6"]' (length=13)
      'parents' => string '1' (length=1)
      'level' => string '2' (length=1)
  3 => 
    array (size=5)
      'id' => string '4' (length=1)
      'type' => string 'team' (length=4)
      'members' => string '["1"]' (length=5)
      'parents' => string '1' (length=1)
      'level' => string '2' (length=1)
  4 => 
    array (size=5)
      'id' => string '5' (length=1)
      'type' => string 'group' (length=5)
      'members' => null
      'parents' => string '1' (length=1)
      'level' => string '2' (length=1)
  5 => 
    array (size=5)
      'id' => string '8' (length=1)
      'type' => string 'team' (length=4)
      'members' => string '["4"]' (length=5)
      'parents' => string '5' (length=1)
      'level' => string '3' (length=1)
  6 => 
    array (size=5)
      'id' => string '9' (length=1)
      'type' => string 'team' (length=4)
      'members' => string '["2"]' (length=5)
      'parents' => string '5' (length=1)
      'level' => string '3' (length=1)
  7 => 
    array (size=5)
      'id' => string '10' (length=2)
      'type' => string 'team' (length=4)
      'members' => null
      'parents' => string '5' (length=1)
      'level' => string '3' (length=1)
  8 => 
    array (size=5)
      'id' => string '11' (length=2)
      'type' => string 'team' (length=4)
      'members' => null
      'parents' => string '5' (length=1)
      'level' => string '3' (length=1)
  9 => 
    array (size=5)
      'id' => string '12' (length=2)
      'type' => string 'group' (length=5)
      'members' => null
      'parents' => string '1' (length=1)
      'level' => string '2' (length=1)
```

the members field has been encoded  as json string. I want to build a array with format as the code below

```
 array('1'=>array(1,2,3,4,5,6),
       '2'=>array(),
       '3'=>array(3,5,6),
       '4'=>array(1),
       '5'=>array(2,4),
       '8'=>array(4),
       '9'=>array(2))
```

The record's id will be key of array and the members has decoded will become the value. I wrote a function handle the array return from the database but the result not as my intention. This is my code

```
$results = mysql_query('select id,type,members,parents,level from team'); 
$array = array();
recursiveDate($results,0,$array);

function recursiveData($sourceArr,$parents = 0, &$newMenu){
        if(count($sourceArr)>0){
            foreach ($sourceArr as $key => $value){
                if($value['parents'] == $parents){
                    if(isset($newMenu[$value['id']])){
                        $newMenu[$value['id']] = array(); 
                    }   
                    $newMenu[$value['id']]  = $value['members']?json_decode($value['members']):array();
                    if(isset($newMenu[$parents])){
                        $newMenu[$parents] = array_merge($newMenu[$value['id']],$newMenu[$parents]);
                    }


                    $newParents = $value['id'];
                    unset($sourceArr[$key]);
                    $this->recursiveData($sourceArr,$newParents, $newMenu);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is the array after handled

```
array (size=10)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '3' (length=1)
      2 => string '5' (length=1)
      3 => string '6' (length=1)
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '3' (length=1)
      1 => string '5' (length=1)
      2 => string '6' (length=1)
  4 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
  5 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '2' (length=1)
      1 => string '4' (length=1)
  8 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '4' (length=1)
  9 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '2' (length=1)
  10 => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  11 => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  12 => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  2 => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

Please help me build that array

Comment: Where are the values of each array coming from? I'm guessing the members?

Comment: Yes, the members field is array has been encoded as a json string and I decoded the members field and set it as the value.

Answer (score 0):

I quickly wrote this so not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for, looks like you over complicated it hugely though. I kept the original result structure incase you wanted that but you can easily overwrite it if you wish.

```
function modifyData($data = array()) {
    foreach($data as &$entry) {
        if(!empty($entry['members'])) {
            $entry['members'] = json_decode($entry['members'], true);
        } else {
            $entry['members'] = array();
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

I tested this with

```
$data = array(
    array(
        'id' =>'1',
        'type' =>'group',
        'members' => null,
        'parents' =>'0',
        'level' =>'1'
    ),
    array(
        'id' =>'1',
        'type' =>'group',
        'members' => '["3","5","6"]',
        'parents' =>'0',
        'level' =>'1'
    ),
    array(
        'id' =>'1',
        'type' =>'group',
        'members' => '["3"]',
        'parents' =>'0',
        'level' =>'1'
    )
);
```

And the output is

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'type' => string 'group' (length=5)
      'members' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'parents' => string '0' (length=1)
      'level' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'type' => string 'group' (length=5)
      'members' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string '3' (length=1)
          1 => string '5' (length=1)
          2 => string '6' (length=1)
      'parents' => string '0' (length=1)
      'level' => string '1' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=5)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'type' => string 'group' (length=5)
      'members' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '3' (length=1)
      'parents' => string '0' (length=1)
      'level' => string '1' (length=1)
```

Comment: In my table, the record has type is group would not save members, only the record has type is team would save members. I want when I access the record is group I can get all members belong to that group and I access the record is team I need to get only members belong to that team. I want the array with key is the id of record and that array will be as the example array('1'=>array(1,2,3,4,5,6),
       '2'=>array(),
       '3'=>array(3,5,6),
       '4'=>array(1),
       '5'=>array(2,4),
       '8'=>array(4),
       '9'=>array(2))

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: The first record in the table is the root. When I get the child node, result will be array('id_of_record'=>decode_members). I want when I get all records, the root contain all members has decoded all child's members field. Thanks for your help